# ALTER TABLEs without AFTER vs ALTER TABLEs with AFTER

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

Say I have these two ALTER TABLEs:

1. `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN colName INT(11) AFTER colName2`
2. `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN colName INT (11)`

Let's say tableName has 400 columns and one million rows. Should those ALTER TABLEs run at the same speed or should one be faster than the other?

Comment: AFAIK there's no speed difference, because the whole table will be modified. The only difference will be that using (2) will put the new column at the end of the table

Comment: 400 columns? You should consider normalizing your data some more :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 columns is terrible :)

In theory both variants will run in same time